# Sorting and saving dataset from open_mfdataset results in memory error

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I am trying to write a script which opens multiple unsorted (in the time dimension) .nc files using xarray.open_mfdataset, sorts them together according to the time dimensions, and then saves them all as one .nc file. The size of the combined dataset is time: 452652, level: 2000.

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_mfdataset('2008_*.nc',combine='nested',concat_dim='time',
                    chunks={'time':10000,'level':2000})
ds = ds.sortby('time')
ds.to_netcdf('2008_trial.nc')
```

There are 25 different .nc files being open, each of which is approximately 6.4mb so the resulting combined .nc file shouldn't be too large (around 150mb).

While running the ds.sortby command, I get the following warning multiple times:

```
PerformanceWarning: Slicing with an out-of-order index is generating 9300 times more chunks
return self.array[key]
```

The .nc files contain 4 different 2D variables and 10 1D variables. When I try to save the ds, it results in a memory error and takes a very long time to run. When I try to save the unsorted ds (without using the sortby command), it executes much faster and results in no memory error.
Most of what I've read makes me think this is a chunk issue.

Also, this is my first posted question here. Please let me know if I am missing any important details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I'll try to help anyway and leave a few thoughts:

- You create chunks along the time dimension. I'm not sure how it works exactly, but I'd imagine it is more straightforward to sortby a dimension that is not chunked (otherwise, items from different chunks have to be compared and rearranged)
- As you say that you'd expect the entire data to fit into your memory anyway: Have you tried to load the data into memory even before sorting? `ds.load()`
- Is the type of your time coordinate an actual datetime, i.e., `datetime64[ns]`? I'm not sure, but maybe it is easier to sort timestamps than, e.g., integers.